# layout issues with css (twitter bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [css styles from Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) but I can't seem to align my "span16" div with my breadcrumb container.  The breadcrumb container is the size I need.  I've attached a screenshot to show the issue.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <li><a href="search.php">Search</a>&raquo;</li>
        <li class="active">Basic</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span16 well">
            <form id="form_id" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span-one-third">
                        Span 1/3
                    </div>
                    <div class="span-one-third">
                        Span 2/3
                    </div>
                    <div class="span-one-third">
                        Span 3/3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can view the full page [here](http://accentudate.com/new/test.html)

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: I'm guessing there is right-side padding or margin on the ul or li tags, but without seeing the full css we can't really tell from just the html. Can you post a link to the full page?

Comment: Ben: I revised the question and posted the URL to the page. Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span16 is wider than the container. The breadcrumb is restricted by the width of the container. Increasing the size of the container will allow the breadcrumb to match up.

Comment: changing the container to 980 worked just fine.  Now everything lines up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The .span16 {} has a static width of 940 but it also has 19px padding applied so it's 940 + 2x19

Comment: Yep, this is it. Change your span16 width and your one-third class (to 286px)